# Sound through the origin computer when using Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, audio

I plan to set up my old laptop as a media center with Windows 7, and I will use remote desktop to connect to it. Will it be possible to play music through the speakers connected to this laptop when I am using remote desktop? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the sound is played on your origin computer by default. To change it, do this:

Open mstsc.exe > Click on "Options" > Local Resources tab > button "Settings..."

[image]